# how align in the same line two <p> paragrapher

Tags: html

I have two

tags one inside the other. The problem is that the

with name "bookmark_corrente_operazioni" is printed in the new line. So this is my code:

```
<p name="copia_operazione_spiegata"><b>Copia</b>: copia i post del bookmark corrente <p name="bookmark_corrente_operazioni">facebook</p>  e di copiarli in uno o più bookmarkk di destinazione</p>
```

and the result is:

```
Copia: copia i post del bookmark corrente
facebook e di copiarli in uno o più bookmark
```

I want that the result is:

```
Copia: copia i post del bookmark corrente facebook e di copiarli in uno o più bookmark
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of a second paragraph tag you can try using a span tag. It will be within the first paragraph tag and will not cause a line break.

e.g.:

```html
<p name="copia_operazione_spiegata"><b>Copia</b>: copia i post del bookmark corrente <span name="bookmark_corrente_operazioni">facebook</span>  e di copiarli in uno o più bookmarkk di destinazione</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using single `<p>` tag or Using `<p>` tag with `<span>` element would do

```html
<p class="copia_operazione_spiegata"><b>Copia</b>: copia i post del bookmark corrente <span class="bookmark_corrente_operazioni">facebook</span>  e di copiarli in uno o più bookmarkk di destinazione</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

is a block element which adds a new line in front of it.   is an inline element which should work better for you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the p element around Facebook

Answer (score 0):

Rather using p use span

```
<p name="copia_operazione_spiegata">
   <b>Copia</b>: copia i post del bookmark corrente 
   <span name="bookmark_corrente_operazioni">facebook</span>  
   e di copiarli in uno o più bookmarkk di destinazione
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

the question is why you'd want to nest paragraphs. thats not a good idea.

instead use `<span>` for what you're trying to achieve. `<p>` is a block element, which means it breaks into a new line after the block.

**the cleanest solution:**

```
<p name="copia_operazione_spiegata"><b>Copia</b>: copia i post del bookmark corrente <span name="bookmark_corrente_operazioni">facebook</span> e di copiarli in uno o più bookmarkk di destinazione</p>
```

that way, you have a wrapping paragraph around your text block, and inside, you have an inline element with `<span>` that doesn't break any rendering. you can apply classes and attributes to it, without worrying it will change the appearance of your wrapping `<p>`

**reason:**

default value for "display" on `<p>` is "block".
default value for "display" on `<span>` is "inline".

Answer (score 0):

You can use a  tag pointing nowhere.

`<a nome="bookmark_corrente_operazioni">facebook</a>`